# Should there be more control over links in user profiles ?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks

I stumbled upon a [user](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/974/reigel) whose "website" in the profile links to an adult dating site.

In the [Content Policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy) it explicitly states that :

> Sexually Explicit Material. Accounts
>   that use Stack Exchange to post
>   sexually explicit or pornographic
>   material, or links to it, will be
>   suspended.

Should there be a way for users to flag a profile, to bring it to the attention of the admins when such things happen ?

ps. Now please don't suspend the guy, he's a legit user, I'm citing the profile as an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know whether a/this dating site qualifies as "Sexually Explicit Material", but if you personally think a link may be offended, feel free to notify either a community moderator or the whole team behind the site.

In many cases it might be enough to mail the user and notify him that a) explicit material will result in suspension, and b) the links in user-submitted content are `rel="nofollow"`, so it will not help to increase your search engine ranking.

You cannot flag a user directly (probably to keep the discussion on the site focused on content, not on individual users), but you can flag *a post from this user* and explain the problem in the main textbox. You can contact the team via the *"contact us"* link at the bottom of each page.